# How do i append a file to another file in php without overriding the first file

Tags: php, append, fwrite

I'm trying to append a second file to the first file and the end of the first file but without overwriting it. I couldn't get it to work. I tried using fwrite and also file_put_content .

```
while(!feof($file))
{
    echo fgets($file)."<br>";
}
fclose($file);

$myfile = fopen("lab5.1.txt", "a") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($myfile))
{
    fwrite($myfile, "lab5.2.txt")."<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: You're just adding the text `lab5.2.txt` to the end of the file because you're not saving the contents of the first file in a variable to be written to the second.

Comment: `file_put_contents` with flag `FILE_APPEND` set, and … done.

Comment: `file_put_contents('file1.xyz', file_get_contents('file2.xyz'), FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: thanks guys, you're all legends . g